# How to use operator `?` to get an item from an array?

Tags: groovy

Groovy code:

```
def line = "aa bb"
println line?.split("\\s+")?[1]
```

I want to use `?` for an array to get an item. If the array is null, then return null, just like `?.`.

But the above code can't be compiled. How to fix it? Or is there any other simple alternative solution to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `getAt` instead of `[]` ([subscript operator](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Operators))

```
def line = "aa bb"
println line?.split("\\s+")?.getAt(1)
```

http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/801001

Answer (score -1):

It's the default behavior for List:

```
println (line?.split("\\s+")as List)[1]
```

Comment: Always throw: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method getAt() on null object`